# still image overlapping jquery image slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

On my main page I'm trying to get an image (logo) to overlap my jquery slideshow. Above the slideshow is a div containing a search bar, the logo should be positioned over top this div and overlap onto the slideshow. Nothing I've tried is working. Appreciate all help, thank you!

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="logo"> <img src="img/logo.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="topbanner">
       <form method="get" action="/search" id="search">
        <input name="searchbar" type="text" size="30" placeholder="Search..." />
    </form> 
</div>

<div id="slides">
    <img src="img/header1.jpg">
    <img src="img/header1.jpg">
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#slides').slidesjs({
        width: 960,
        height: 350,
        play: {
            active: true,
            interval: 4000,
            swap: true
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: please provide jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

By default, elements that come further down the page in your code will overlap elements further up the page. To change this, you must provide a CSS `position` attribute on a container and use `z-index` on the child elements to determine a stacking order. For example:

```
.container {
  position:relative;
}

.logo {
  z-index: 10;
}

#slides {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

That should be enough to at least start with the right overlapping order.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it correctly, then it should work with setting

```
.logo {
    position:relative; 
    margin-bottom: -XXpx;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

This way, your logo should simply go XX pixels down from its normal position.

You might as well wrap #slides into a #slides-container, set to position:relative
with your .logo position:absolute inside.

```
#slides-container {
    position:relative; 
    overflow:visible;
}

.logo {
    position:absolute; 
    top:-XX; 
    right:XX;

}
```

Hope this helps.